# SQLite Queries Extremely Slow in Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

So I am trying to use SQLite with a fairly basic SQL query (for those not familiar with GLOB, its similar to LIKE):

```sql
SELECT * FROM dictionary where word GLOB '[paple][paple][paple][paple][paple]';
```

I can run this in SQLite Manager and it takes around 50ms to retrieve all the records. Now I write the following code in Java and it takes almost 1.5 seconds which seems ridiculously slow in comparison. I understand that it might take a bit longer but 1450ms longer is unacceptably slow:

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dictionary.sqlite");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dictionary where word GLOB '[paple][paple][paple][paple][paple]';");

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("word = " + rs.getString("word"));
}

rs.close();
conn.close();

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Took: " + (end - start));
```

I have a feeling that every time I call ResultSet.next() it has to re-query the database since it doesn't get all the records right away but I'm not 100% sure. I feel like there should be a much more efficient way to do this. So my question is does anyone know how to improve the Java code to be much faster?

PS: I am using [sqliteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). Could the implementation here be slowing me down? Just a thought I had.

Comment: Where exactly is the 1.4 seconds spent?  The getConnection()? The executiveQuery()?  Either add addtiional print statements or consider using logging to get timestamps on your lines which you can then derive the time spent from.

Comment: executeQuery: 438ms. 
ResultSet Iteration Took: 1046ms.

Comment: Both of those timed pieces seem to take quite a bit of time, more so than I think they should. The database table is quite large, approximately 80,000 records, but given the discrepency between my code and the database manager I would venture that I'm doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Probably the regular expression which require all lines to be scanned every time.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call [`ResultSet#getString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29), you're forcing a lot of work to be done. See [the JDBC driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)'s code for [its internal method `RS#findColumn(String)`](https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc/blob/master/src/org/sqlite/RS.java#L102). Note that it doesn't cache the column-name-to-column-ordinal-index mapping. For every row in the result set you inspect, you're suffering multiple string comparison and case conversion operations.

Try replacing your use of `ResultSet#getString(String)` with [`ResultSet#getString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29). First, early on *outside the `while` loop*, figure out the index of the column you wish to extract. (Note that it would be much better to replace your `SELECT *` with an explicit column list, in which case you'd already know the ordinal index of each column.)

```
final int indexWord = rs.findColumn("word");
```

Then, during iteration, use the previously-determined index:

```
// Avoid concatenating:
System.out.print("word = ");
System.out.println(rs.getString(indexWord));
```

Let us know whether that optimization has a noticeable impact.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old :) but we had exactly the same issue: a query that returns ~1500 results, executes in 50-100ms in the SQLite CLI, executes in 40'000 ms with the JDBC driver.

99% of the time was spent in rs.next

We upgraded the sqlite-jdbc library from 3.7 to latest (3.8.11) and the performance was roughly multiplied by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

The Java code looks fine to me. The main issue is that it is going to do a linear table scan, which could be rather slow on a large database, and an index on the `word` column won't help (or at least won't help a lot).

What is the underlying version of SQLite that you're using? Using the current release might enable more optimizations. (I ask because sqliteJDBC is a few years old, yet SQLite is embedded into the driver — of course, since it's an embedded database and not a DB server — and there's been quite a few releases since then.)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem using a small database. My code was similar to this:

```
public LinkedList<Person> getByType(Type type) {
    LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE type_id = " + String.valueOf(type.getId());

    try {

        ResultSet rs = executeQuery(query); // Just calls statement.executeQuery(query);
        logTimestamp("After executeQuery");

        while (rs.next()) {
            logTimestamp("After rs.next");

            Person person = buildPersonFromResultSet(rs); // Just instances a new Person(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name"));
            logTimestamp("After buildPersonFromResultSet");

            list.add(person);
            logTimestamp("After list.add");

            // Each loop iteration takes less than 1 ms
        }

        // list.size() is 26

        logTimestamp("After the last rs.next"); // After the last rs.next(), it was taking 4 seconds!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not list. Query=[" + query + "]", e);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Through timestamped logs, I noticed that a slowdown of 4 seconds was happening only in the last call to the `rs.next()` method. I took a look at the SQLite JDBC driver source code (https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/src) and saw that there are a lot of stuff happening when the "fetch" cursor finds out he is on the last row. I tried to increase the statement's fetch size (as pointed out in other answers), but no success. I heard that the database tables should be indexed to ease that job. When I checked my tables, I was surprised because there was no indexes in the primary and foreign keys. Some database tools don't create indexes by default, so I did it and now the last iteration takes less than 1ms too.

**So, summing up:**

My SQLite database had no indexes. After creating them for the primary and foreign keys, all the loop takes 20 ms instead of 4 seconds.